# What's the process for getting a plug in in wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress.com

What's the process for getting a plug in in wordpress.com? Do they pick plug ins from the same directory as a local Wordpress installation? Is there any further approval?

We are considering making a Wordpress plug in but it only makes sense if people with blogs at wordpress.com can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [WordPress.com Plugin support article](http://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/) - it seems it really is a case of the WP.com team deciding which plugins have the green light, partly based on user suggestions and demands.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Wordpress.com or self-hosted Wordpress? I'd suspect it's difficult to get .com to accept and use a plugin, while there are millions of people who self-host Wordpress and can install any plugins they want: [WordPress › WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/)

Comment: I'm talking about Wordpress.com, the service, not Wordpress(.org) the open source product that anyone can self-host.